# Is there any rust function available for getParsedAccountInfo similar to typescript from solana/web3 library?

Tags: solana-program, web3.js, anchor-lang, anchor-spl

I am trying to derive AccountInfo from given public key on Rust, Is there any similar anchor function available like getParsedAccountInfo from solana/web3 library?

Answer (score 1):

The official [solana_account_decoder crate](https://docs.rs/solana-account-decoder/latest/solana_account_decoder/) can help you.

Comment: which function can be used for AccountInfo parsing?

Answer (score 1):

Yes! The rpc client provided by `solana-rpc-client` has `get_account_with_config` that lets you specify it:

```
let account_address = Pubkey::new(...);
let rpc_client = solana_rpc_client::rpc_client::RpcClient("...");
let account = rpc_client.get_account_with_config(
    &account_address,
    solana_rpc_client_api::config::RpcAccountInfoConfig {
        encoding: Some(solana_account_decoder::UiAccountEncoding::JsonParsed),
        ..Default::default()
    }
);
```

This is actually what `getParsedAccountInfo` is doing under the hood.

More info at https://docs.rs/solana-rpc-client/latest/solana_rpc_client/rpc_client/struct.RpcClient.html#method.get_account_with_config